# How to write a function taking limit of multivariables in sequence?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, function-construction

I'm trying to write a function to calculate the limit of a function on a number of variables in sequence. 
Here I take a function with four variables `x`, `y`, `z`, `t` but the number of variables is not fixed. 
How can I do that?

```
Limit[f[x,y,z,t], {x->x0, y->y0, z->z0, t->t0}] = Limit[Limit[Limit[Limit[f[x,y,z,t], {x->x0}],{y->y0}],{z->z0}],t->t0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining this recursively:

```
MyLimit[expression_, {initialVariables__, x_ -> x0_}] := 
 Limit[MyLimit[expression, {initialVariables}], {x -> x0}]

MyLimit[expression_, {x_ -> x0_}] := Limit[expression, {x -> x0}]
```